# How to validate data from a controller in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have data in my controller that is being received from another rails app and database (**this has to be in the controller**) I want to get this data so I can validate it in my model before allowing another step in a wizard (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309688/how-to-validate-in-a-model-data-from-a-controller) for some code examples)

**My Problem** is that I cannot directly grab this data from the controller in my model as this violates MVC.

**My Question** is how would I go about checking the controllers data in my Model?

- Do I have to load this data / true - false response in a view and then link this to my Model? (I don't really want this to show in the view and haven't quite worked out how to do this)
- Do I need to pass this data to a route i.e `example/data.json` and then check this in my Model? (I also haven't worked out how to use this data.json from there in my model)

Any help / steering in the right direction would be very useful. (**also i cannot use a gem to do this**)

Comment: Does the information coming in from the request translate into a 'state' for the Object?  If so, you could set the state on the object and then use that to validate in the model.  Usually things in the controller relating to the request, time, session, params, etc. should stay there.  Things that relate to the model should go on the model.  Can you update the object and set a valid state information on the model?

Comment: The data comes in then I basically want to check if the data exists or not I can make the controller return true/false in its method but it must exist in the controller. I then want to get this response from the controller and use it to validate my model. Have you got any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please be double double sure that you don't validate a model by data which it does not contain by itself. Model should validate its current state but **not** a way it came to this state (e.g. which user put a model to this state).

At second, you should never use controller methods in a model. If controller contains some business logic, extract that logic into a third class which will be used by both controller and model.

Moreover, you have a data in a controller and you have an access to the model, right?. Therefore, if you are in a controller method, for instance in a before filter or action, you could take that data and pass it to the model, like this:

```
def controller method
  hey_model.is_this_correct?(data)
end
```

If you say that that data must be checked **after** controller has responded to a request (for example, at the next wizard step, i.e. at the next request), then you definitely must store that value somewhere between requests.

This is the very point of stateless HTTP. No data is saved between requests until you explicitly do that. You could store your value in cookies or in database.

Comment: The data comes from another rails app database (makes a request from a controller) this controller must contain this data request method it cannot go anywhere else. the model validation would be something like this `validate :data_presence, if => lambda { |0| 0.current_step == "step1" }` `def data_presence #check controller data exists or true / false response etc end` the data comes from a database and I would like to get away from storing this again although if I need to place it somewhere on that step1 view or a route that would be acceptable can you make any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion #1. Change a logic of your wizard (not an easy task).

Suggestion #2. Save current step temporarily in the model's table (it smells)

Suggestion #3. Save that data in cookies/session or pass it to the next step form and make it insert that data into the next request.

Comment: By the way, `|0| 0.current_step` <-- this is not going to work, you can't do that with integers

Comment: Woops sorry meant to be `o` not `0` will have a look and see what I can do thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the answer I wanted really although I had other people answering on the other question, some good ways to implement this thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question was a while ago but for those who are still searching, I found the exact answer, how to pass the information from the controller to a model.

With this line everything is solved

```
var = request.env['target_model'].sudo().function_in_your_model(data)
```

`var` is a variable in case you need to handle that data in the controller, `target_model` is the model where you want to send the data, `function_in_your_model` is the function where you are going to handle the data already in the model, and inside this function you send the data that you need.