# Rails - How can I sum all the fields and use the sum as a validation before entering values in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, attributes, virtual

I have a form containing multiple fields that have integer inputs. I have basic validation on the fields like presence, inclusion, and numericality. The part that I am stuck at however is checking that the sum of all the fields is equal to 100. I need to find a way to sum up all the values in the fields and ensure they add up to one hundred with a validator. I considered using a virtual attribute that would do the summing of the fields, and then use a validator on that value, however, I am not exactly sure how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
A confused rails beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom validation method: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods for more.

So for instance try something like the following where field1 and field2 are attributes on your model:

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :sum_equals_100

  def sum_equals_100
     if field1 + field2 != 100
       errors.add(:base, 'fields must sum to 100')
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: In the custom validation method you can sum up the fields on the model to see if they equal 100 percent. I've updated the answer with an example to try and demonstrate.

Comment: I will give a try right now, thanks so much. I think my issue is accessing the fields directly from the model. When I tried earlier I received some errors, but hopefully it will work this time around

Comment: Ah, the error with doing it that way is the way my form is constructed. I made it so the number of fields can change, depending on how many assignment types are added (http://pastebin.com/Qh7sC6ur) so I cannot access the values via attributes directly. Thats why i thought a virtual attribute would be best, but i am not sure how to implement it

Comment: @soliman You can access instance variables in your validation method. So if assignment_types is an instance variable in your model, you can check that the types stored in the assignment_types variable sum up to a certain value in the validation method. Validation methods allow you to run any code you want to validate your method, so you should be able to use the validation method to validate what is stored in your assignment_types variable.

Comment: I cant access the instance variables belonging to the controller in the model. The problem I am having is how do i pass the sum value to the model to validate it?

Comment: @soliman give this link a try, it sounds similar to what you are trying to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309688/how-to-validate-in-a-model-data-from-a-controller

Comment: thank you, i will take a look into that and let you know if it works. Also, is it considered bad practice to do the validation for the sum in the controller? couldnt i simply sum the weights, do a conditional so if sum = 100 perform the update, otherwise, warn the user?

Comment: Models are meant to manage application state. Each model should manage it's own data including tasks such as validation. If the data you are validating is somehow outside of the model or is related directly to the incoming request, you can validate things inside the controller, but any data the model is managing should ideally be validated in the model. This means the model can ensure a consistent, valid state and be used in various places around your application without worry.